# Add a column to spark dataframe whose value is hashMod of the existing dataframe row

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to add a column to spark dataframe whose value is hashMod of the existing dataframe row. In the below example,I  could achieve the same for hash of 1 specific column "data", how do I achieve the same for whole dataframe row (allcolumns)?

```
object Container {
  case class intContainer(data: Int)
}


val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._    
val getBucket = udf((data: Object) => data.hashCode() %10 )
val schema = StructType(List(StructField("age", IntegerType)))

val userList = List(( 23),( 24), (25), (57) )
val df1:RDD[Container.intContainer] = sc.parallelize(userList).map(x=> Container.intContainer(x))
val df = df1.toDF()
df.registerTempTable("dfcount")
val countdf = sqlContext.sql("select data,data+1 as count, current_timestamp() as time  from dfcount")
val xx = countdf.withColumn("bucket_id", getBucket( col("data")))
```

Comment: how many number of possible columns could be there in df?

Answer (score 1):

The below snippets employs an udf that takes an array of columns whose hashcode is summed to get the bucket value. This function works for any arbitary number of columns and for any schema.

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
def hasher(data: AnyRef *) = (data.map(_.hashCode).sum % 10)
val getBucket = udf(hasher _)
val df = sc.parallelize(('a' to 'z').map(_.toString) zip (1 to 30)).toDF("c1","c2")
df.withColumn("bucket", getBucket(array(df.columns.map(df.apply): _*))).show()
+---+---+------+
| c1| c2|bucket|
+---+---+------+
|  a|  1|     6|
|  b|  2|     8|
|  c|  3|     0|
|  d|  4|     2|
|  e|  5|     4|
|  f|  6|     6|
|  g|  7|     8|
|  h|  8|     0|
|  i|  9|     2|
|  j| 10|     3|
|  k| 11|     5|
|  l| 12|     7|
|  m| 13|     9|
|  n| 14|     1|
|  o| 15|     3|
|  p| 16|     5|
|  q| 17|     7|
|  r| 18|     9|
|  s| 19|     1|
|  t| 20|     4|
+---+---+------+
```